# Visitor Implementation: Constant versus Mutable Visitor

Tags: c++, inheritance, visitor-pattern, const-correctness

Given that the difference between a **constant** visitor and a **mutable** visitor is that the methods in a constant visitor are not allowed to modify the visited object.

```
class Integer_Field;
class Boolean_Field;
class Text_Field;

class Visitor_Constant
{
  public:
    virtual void visit(const Integer_Field& f) = 0;
    virtual void visit(const Boolean_Field& f) = 0;
    virtual void visit(const Text_Field& f) = 0;
};

class Visitor_Mutable
{
  public:
    virtual void visit(Integer_Field& f) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Boolean_Field& f) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Text_Field& f) = 0;
};
```

I would like to minimize support for these visitors.  For example, if I come up with a class `Blob_Field`, I need to modify both classes.  I would prefer to have something where I only have to modify one class or stencil.

The maintenance issue fans out when there are many classes defined from these parent visitors.  This is the main reason I want to simplify the maintenance.

**My questions:**
*(Note:  This must be resolved without using C++11 features as my development environment does not support C++11 and I'm not allowed to upgrade at this time.)*

1. Is there a way to use the `template` mechanism to merge the two
   (such as supply 'const' as a parameter to the template)?
2. How can I set up these visitors so that I can pass a
   `Visitor_Constant` to methods using a `Visitor_Mutable`?

*Note:  Combining these classes via a parent class, doubles the visitor methods that must be implemented and maintained.*

**Edit 1: Class relationships**

```
class Component; // Base class for fields and records.
class Field : public Component; // Base class for all fields
class Record : public Component // Base class for all records
{
  std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Component> > component_container;
};
class Integer_Field : public Field;
class Boolean_Field : public Field;
class Text_Field : public Field;
```

**Edit 2: Rationality of fields**
One rationality for the fields being treated specifically is the case of generating an SQL statement for creating a table.
Another is for loading fields from a database table.

Comment: How are the "field" classes related?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The fields classes are components of a record, such as in a database / table record.

Comment: Disregarding the `const` issue for now, you can let each `visit` function correspond to a specific interface. The Visitor needs only implement the interfaces that it handles (and these might be arranged in some hierarchical fashion to support a hierarchy of types). The field object being visited can then `dynamic_cast` the visitor down to the interface corresponding to its own basic type, and if such interface is present, call its function. This centralizes the explicit downcasting. In contrast, your scheme above doesn't need any downcasting, but has that potential maintainance prblm

Comment: As I recall, Andrei Alexandrescu provided a nice overview and trade-off analysis for various visitor pattern implementations, in his book "Modern C++ Design". It's possible that some of that is supported by the Loki library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the `template` mechanism to merge the two (such as supply 'const' as a parameter to the template)?

You can supply it through a template template parameter, and also keep the pure visitor implementation generic. I originally did this in C++11, but since you say you don't have it, I'll present one with type lists instead.

Here is the type list implementation.

```
/* Our empty node for our type list. */
class Empty {};

/* Cons for our type list. */
template <typename First_, typename Rest_>
class Cons {
  public:

  /* First type */
  typedef First_ First;

  /* Rest.  */
  typedef Rest_ Rest;

};  // Cons<First_, Rest_>
```

Here is the generic visitor implementation.

```
/* Forward declaration. */
template <template <typename> class Decorator, typename Members>
class VisitorRecur;

/* Base case. */
template <template <typename> class Decorator, typename Member>
class VisitorRecur<Decorator, Cons<Member, Empty> > {
  public:

  /* Pure virtual for each of the members. */
  virtual void operator()(
      typename Decorator<Member>::Type that) const = 0;

};  // VisitorRecur<Decorator, Member>

/* Recursive case. */
template <template <typename> class Decorator, typename Members>
class VisitorRecur
    : public VisitorRecur<Decorator, typename Members::Rest> {
  public:

  /* Bring the operator()s into scope. */
  using VisitorRecur<Decorator, typename Members::Rest>::operator();

  /* Pure virtual for each of the members. */
  virtual void operator()(
      typename Decorator<typename Members::First>::Type that) const = 0;

};  // VisitorRecur<Decorator, typename Members::Rest>

/* Final visitor. */
template <template <typename> class Decorator, typename Members>
class Visitor : public VisitorRecur<Decorator, Members> {
  public:

  /* Bring the operator()s into scope. */
  using VisitorRecur<Decorator, Members>::operator();

};  // Visitor<Decorator, Members>
```

Here are the two decorators that we'll define.

```
/* ConstRef. */
template <typename T>
class ConstRef {
  public:

  typedef const T & Type;

};  // ConstRef<T>

/* Ref. */
template <typename T>
class Ref {
  public:

  typedef T & Type;

};  // Ref<T>
```

Here is the use case for it.

```
/* Forward declarations. */
class Circle;
class Square;
class Triangle;

/* Add the members into a type list. */
typedef Cons<Circle, Cons<Square, Cons<Triangle, Empty> > > Members;

/* Our const visitor which accepts the members by const-ref. */
typedef Visitor<ConstRef, Members> ConstVisitor;

/* Our mutating visitor which accepts the members by ref. */
typedef Visitor<Ref, Members> MutatingVisitor;
```